# ActionListener in expandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, actionlistener

I created an expandableListView in android in which the child contains two buttons.

The actionlisterner of these buttons are in another class . How can I let the actionListeners to be called once buttons in the child view is clicked?

This is what i tried to do:

```
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    Button b1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);


    classWithListeners p = new ClassWithListeners(b1,b2);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have the ClassWithListeners implement whatever actionListener you want to listen for (i.e. onClickListener)

and then do

```
ClassWithListeners p = new ClassWithListeners(b1,b2);
b1.setOnClickListener(p);
b2.setOnClickListener(p);
```